# Use a Local Model file for Online Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-navisworks

I would like to be able to use a local navisworks or revit file to be available when using an online viewer app on forge.

I have so far followed the tutorial here - https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/datamanagement/oss/ that allows me to upload a file for viewing from the client side. I would like to remove the ability to upload from the client side and choose a local file to be viewed instead.

I would also like to know how to remove additional buckets / objects placed from the client side from the side menu (circled in the image)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All our sample apps work like this (e.g. https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewmodels/tree/nodejs):

- all the **client-side** content (html, js, css) is in a specific folder (in case of **nodejs** samples it's called `public`)
- all the rest is part of the **server-side**
- all the **Forge** related functionality is exposed to the **client-side** through **server-side** endpoints

When the page is opened then the browser fetches the **client-side** components (1) - i.e. html, css, js files
When needed, the **client-side** code calls an endpoint on the **server** (2) which in turn reaches out to **Forge** (3) and passes back the result to the client
The only **client-side** part that communicates **directly** with **Forge** is the **Viewer** (4)

[image]

If you want to remove some of the functionality presented to the user, you can just remove them from the client-side part (e.g. from the **html** file)

In the server-side code, you can also combine multiple **Forge** calls: e.g. create a bucket, upload model file into it from the server, translate the model to **SVF**

If there are operations you only want to do **just once** (e.g. delete a bucket), you can also use utilities like https://oss-manager.autodesk.io/ or use this **Visual Studio Code Extension**: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-visual-studio-code

If you want to add controls to the toolbar this should be of help: https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/extensions 
If you want to add something **custom** then you can use **HTML**/**CSS**/**JS** in your **client-side** code to implement those